# CSS Data-Badge, Value not appearing from database

Tags: php, html, css

I have this list in welcome.php

```
<li>
                       <a href="#" class="badge1" data-badge="<?php echo "$row_cnt"; ?>" value = "<?php echo "$row_cnt"; ?>"><img src="images/referral.png" > Referral</a>
                    </li>
```

Here I am trying to populate the circle with value from database. I am getting the right value, but its not appearing in the circle. Pardon my CSS please. 
Copied this code from here http://www.cssportal.com/blog/create-css-notification-badge/

In the same welcome.php, CSS code is

```
 .badge1 {
position:relative;
}
.badge1[data-badge]:before {
 content:attr(data-badge);
 position:absolute;
 top:0px;
 right:0px;
 font-size:.7em;
 background:green;
 color:white;
 width:18px;height:18px;
 text-align:center;
 line-height:18px;
 border-radius:50%;
 box-shadow:0 0 1px #211;
 }
```

The php value I am trying to echo here comes from a php block after this code. 
Code is:

```
<html><li>
<a href="#" class="badge1" data-badge="<?php echo "$row_cnt"; ?>" value = "
<?php echo "$row_cnt"; ?>"><img src="images/referral.png" > Referral</a>
                    </li>
</html>

<?php 
// Get $row_cnt
?>
```

So how do I access this $row_cnt value above?

Any help would be helpful.

Comment: Can you post your html code from DOM inspector ?

Comment: <a href="#" class="badge1" data-badge="value" ==""><img src="images/referral.png"> Referral</a>

Comment: I have to echo the value in data-badge or value?

Answer (score 0):

You can not put " inside " so use the escape \ before it
or remove it in echo before the variable

Answer (score 0):

Remove quotation marks:

```
<?php echo $row_cnt; ?>
```

or even

```
<?=$row_cnt?>
```

Comment: <a href="#" class="badge1" data-badge=<?php echo $row_cnt;?>   value = <?php echo $row_cnt?>><img src="images/referral.png" > Referral</a> Doesnt work

Comment: how do you assign the value to begin with?

Comment: See my edit. The value I am echoing is retrived in a php block after this.

Comment: That is why it doesn't work. You must assign the value to the variable before you can retrieve it. Move the "get" part up before you use it.